# jWebsocket: unable to deploy in Tomcat

Tags: websocket

when I tried to deploy jwebsocket war into Tomcat 6 am getting this while starting the server

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jwebsocket.appserver.ContextListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [d:\Tomcat6]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:85)

any idea how to resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missed the config xml files when added it works